# Edit the default Webkit developer tools layout?

Tags: web-developer-toolbar

Every time I open the Webkit dev tools, I have to go through a bunch of extra steps to set up the layout how I like:

- open the global debug console
- drag it to be taller
- switch to network tab
- view only XHR & WebSockets network activity

Is there a way I can store this layout as my default so I don't need to go through this process every time I open a new tab?

It's not that bad, but one of those things that gets annoying after the 1000th time...